# How to stop resource c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Using two threads which print numbers in list . But few numbers are repeated . I used semaphore to lock which is not working . Am I doing something wrong 
? Need help!

```
class Program
{
    public static int count=0;
    public static List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
    public static int semaphore=0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            numbers.Add(i.ToString());
        }

       Console.WriteLine("Before start thread");

       Thread tid1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThread.Thread1));
       Thread tid2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThread.Thread1));

       tid1.Start();
       tid2.Start();
    }
}

public class MyThread
{
    public static void Thread1()
    {
        for (; Program.count < Program.numbers.Count;)
        {
            if (Program.semaphore != 1)
            {
                Program.semaphore = 1;
                Console.WriteLine(Program.numbers[Program.count]);
                Program.count++;
                Program.semaphore = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your semaphore is not a [Semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx), it is an `Int32`. It is not even `volatile`, and even if it had been it would not have helped due to the race [condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) between checking and setting it.

Comment: How can I solve it ?

Comment: @phpnet The best solution is that you begin with reading some articles about multithreading and locking. We can write you 5 lines that work, but it would be nearly useless. They would work in *this* specific case.

Comment: If you want to roll something that does not need standard sync primitives, then read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion. But usually you should just use some standard [Monitor/Mutex/ReaderWriterLock...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx)

Comment: I normally suggest http://www.albahari.com/threading/ as a complete resource about multithreading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition:

- Thread 1 executes `if (Program.semaphore != 1)` and sees that it is not 1.
- Simultaneously, Thread 2 also executes `if (Program.semaphore != 1)` and sees that it is not 1.
- Therefore both threads proceed into the body of the `if`.

To fix this, you should use a `lock`:

```
public class MyThread
{
    public static object locker = new object();

    public static void Thread1()
    {
        for (; Program.count < Program.numbers.Count;)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (Program.count < Program.numbers.Count)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Program.numbers[Program.count]);
                    Program.count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the following naïve solution still has a race condition, and will not work:

```
public class MyThread
{
    public static object locker = new object();

    public static void Thread1()
    {
        for (; Program.count < Program.numbers.Count;)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Program.numbers[Program.count]);
                Program.count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's because the check in the `for` loop is done outside the lock, and therefore `Program.count` may have been incremented by another thread between the check made in the `for` loop and the `lock` being entered.